# ASP.net MVC Dropdownlist Troubles

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am having a bit of trouble with A dropdownlist that is supposed to be populated with values that correspond to ID keys in a database. So ideally i want something that looks like this in the dropdown list

value="0" USA
  value="1" ETC

and my code behind looks like this

```
    public TabletViewModel(Tablet tablet)
    {
        Tablet = tablet;
        //AreaHelper.Areas, tablet.Location.Name
        Areas = new SelectList(AreaHelper.Areas, tablet.Location.Name);
    }
```

whenever I try to add overflow methods to the selectlist constructor I get exception errors when I try to add the LocationID

anyone have any ideaS?

Comment: What type of errors are you getting?

Comment: DataBinding: 'System.String' does not contain a property with the name 'AWING'.

when i change my constructor to : Areas = new SelectList(AreaHelper.Areas, tablet.Location.Name, tablet.LocationID.ToString());

Comment: I am new here, can any one tell me what is the 3rd line of the code doing !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the issue, the IEnumerable i was passing was a specific column, not the whole table, so when i tried to do

new SelectList(AreaHelper.Areas, tablet.Location.Name, tablet.LocationID.ToString())

and got the error: "String doesn't contain property Name"

now everything is working fine

Answer (score 0):

Does your list AreaHelper.Areas support IEnumerable?

Is tablet, tablet.Location or tablet.Location.Name Null?

Comment: the AreaHelper.Areas is an Ienumerable that returns the names of the areas, and the tablet.Location is a table of locations, and the tablet.Location.Name is not null, its the name associated with locationID, I just want the locationId to be the value associated with each option